# Get Facebook user info in batch requests?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook

I can use the following `https://graph.facebook.com/user_id` to get user's data (like `name`, `gender` etc.).

Is there a way I can do something similar to
`https://graph.facebook.com/user1_id, user2_id, user3_id, ...` ?
so I will get all the data in one request?

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/user1_id, user2_id, user3_id in this link what are you expecting with user1_id, user2_id,.... whether this are friends of logged in users or something else?

Comment: @cloudlight `user1_id, user2_id, ...` they are friend's of my app users. I only need their name basically

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I tried following line and it is working.

https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=19292868552,bharatpatil007,220439

And it is working. It's result is as follows

```
{
   "19292868552": {
      "id": "19292868552",
      "name": "Facebook Platform",
      "picture": "http://profile.cc.fbcdn.net/hprofile-cc-ash2/211033_19292868552_7506301_s.jpg",
      "link": "http://www.facebook.com/platform",
      "likes": 2479998,
      "category": "Product/service",
      "website": "http://developers.facebook.com",
      "username": "platform",
      "founded": "May 2007",
      "company_overview": "Facebook Platform enables anyone to build social apps on Facebook and the web.",
      "mission": "To make the web more open and social."
   },
   "220439": {
      "id": "220439",
      "name": "Bret Taylor",
      "first_name": "Bret",
      "last_name": "Taylor",
      "link": "http://www.facebook.com/btaylor",
      "username": "btaylor",
      "gender": "male",
      "locale": "en_US"
   },
   "bharatpatil007": {
      "id": "793619474",
      "name": "Bharat Patil",
      "first_name": "Bharat",
      "last_name": "Patil",
      "link": "http://www.facebook.com/bharatpatil007",
      "username": "bharatpatil007",
      "gender": "male",
      "locale": "en_US"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your comment
**First you will need to get the permissions to access friends info using following line [EDIT]**

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
 array(
 'redirect_uri' =>'http://apps.facebook.com/yourappname/'
 ,'scope' => 'friends_about_me')
);
```

Following line will give you friends of your app user.

```
$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends?access_token='.$accessToken.'&fields=id');
```

condense those IDs into a comma-separated string

```
$friends_ids;
foreach ($friends['data'] AS $friendsInfo)
{
  $friends_ids .= $friendsInfo['id'] .',';
}
```

remove last comma

```
$friends_ids = substr($friends_ids, 0, -1);
```

now query for friends' name and gender **(Following line is what you needed)**

```
$friends_info = $facebook->api('/?access_token='.$accessToken.'&fields=name,gender&ids='.$friends_ids);
```

Comment: There might changes in API with the new version.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. But I think you misunderstood my comment, I said `they are friend's of my app users.`. So yes `user1_id, ... userN_id` are friends of my app users. But a current user `A` can be seeing the names of `user1_id, ..., userN_id` without being friends with them. `user1_id, ... userN_id` could be friends of user `B` who is using my app. Sorry for the misunderstanding :( ... Do you know if I could do something like this : `https://graph.facebook.com/ids=[user1_id, user2_d]`??